# vb6 control finding in form

Tags: vb.net, datagrid, vb6

i am working for conversion of desktop app to web app for that 
i have vb6 application running in my pc and i have to implement the functionality according to behavior of vb6 application, the problem is that the datagrid which is displayed i cant found on vb6 application code
so how to i found which form contain that particular dataGrid?

for example in in web app we can find the datagrid using firebug by inspecting element , so is there any way to find the datagrid in vb6 application

sorry for asking such silly question but actually i have no any idea about vb6 desktop application development
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you have the source code, you can do a file search on the .frm files.  They are actually text files and the controls are in the first part of the file, or you could search for the form name or any unique text on the form which might be in the source.

To poke around the running application, if you have Visual Studio (not VB6), you can use Spy++.  If not, you can try some of the alternatives, such as http://www.catch22.net/software/winspy-17  They might give you a clue as to where to look.